# I need to search a string in data file. but the string is written in another file

Tags: python, file

I have key words to be search in one file let say abc.txt and in another file I have my data, def.txt.
I want a code in python to find key words written in abc.txt, in def.txt and if present, print those line in a new file.
Thank you.
I tried writing a code but it didn't work.
following is the code I write.

```
f = open('/home/vivek/Documents/abc.txt')
f1 = open('output.txt', 'a')
f2 = open('/home/vivek/Documents/def.txt', 'r')

# doIHaveToCopyTheLine=False

for line in f.readlines():
      if f2 in line:
        f1.write(line)

f1.close()
f.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: did you want to search the entire file f2 is in file f or lines of f2 in f ?

Comment: why don't you create a new python file keyword.py and store key words in it then search accordingly in your def.txt?

Comment: for small enough inputs, you can save all lines from def.txt in an array using `readlines`.. then you could test `if line in f2_lines` where f2_lines is the array with all lines

Comment: also, with grep command, it is as simple as `grep -xFf abc.txt def.txt > output.txt`

Comment: while reading again your question a clarification needed that actually you want to search with abc.txt or search in abc.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the keywords into a list then you can check the other file line-by-line, and write to `outfile` as you find keywords in the line.

```
with open('/path/to/keywords.txt') as f:
    keywords = set(line.strip() for line in f) # assuming words are separated by line

with open('/path/to/search_me.txt') as f, open('/path/to/outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in f:
        if any(kw in line for kw in keywords):
            outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should record all the words in abc.txt use a set and then search them in def.txt

```
word_set = set()
with open('/home/vivek/Documents/abc.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        word_set.add(line.strip())
f1 = open('output.txt', 'a')
with open('/home/vivek/Documents/def.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        find = False
        for word in word_set:
            if word in line:
                find = True
                break
        if find:
            f1.write(line)
f1.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
with open("keyword.txt", "r") as keyword_file:
    keywords = keyword_file.read().strip()
    keywords = keywords.split()

with open("data.txt", "r") as data_file, open("output.txt", "w") as output_file:
    for line in data_file.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        for word in keywords:
            if line.find(word) != -1:
                print line
                output_file.writelines(line + '\n')
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to sytech's answer you may try this:

```
with open('def.txt') as kw_obj, open('abc.txt') as in_obj:
    keywords = set(kw_obj.read().split())
    in_lines = in_obj.readlines()
    match_lines = [line for keyword in keywords for line in in_lines if keyword in line]

if match_lines:
    with open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
        out.write(''.join(match_lines))
```